# Table insertion by Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here's the table:

```
         Order [OrderId], [DateTimePlaced], [ProductId], [Quantity]
         Invoice [InvoiceId], [invoice_DateTime], [order_Id]
```

I want SQL Server automatically inserts the data into the Invoice table while I manually insert the data into Order table.

Here is my code:

```
     create trigger invoice_Sync on Order
     after insert
     as
     begin

     insert into Invoice (invoice_DateTime,order_Id) select ID,Name,Address
     select getdate(),OrderId
     from inserted
     go
```

However, after I executed this query, SQL Server gave me an error "The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list"

My situation is: The invoice Id is set to be automatically incremented, So I think I should not manually put the Invoice Id into this trigger.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `SELECT` there:

```
 create trigger invoice_Sync on Order
 after insert
 as
 begin

 insert into Invoice (invoice_DateTime,order_Id) 
 --select ID,Name,Address, Why is this here?
 select getdate(),OrderId
 from inserted
 end
 go
```

Comment: That was my fault, thanks for noticing. However, I amended my code, now I got this error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure invoice_Sync, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'inserted'.

Comment: @X.YangUK Ok, updated my answer to add an `END` before the `GO`